# Windows 7 BSOD opening IC from Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, bsod

BSOD seems to happen only trying to accessing IC from Chrome.

Windows says:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   3b
  BCP1: 00000000C0000005
  BCP2: FFFFF8800DA0937D
  BCP3: FFFFF8800D343BE0
  BCP4: 0000000000000000
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  256_1
```

with this dump file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rwjp2li2c0540z3/092215-7846-01.dmp?dl=0

Indeed it seems that Windows Update recognizes the driver for IC as assigned to SPUVCbv_x64.sys

```
<DEVICE>
    <DESCRIPTION>Integrated Camera</DESCRIPTION>
    <HARDWAREID>USB\VID_5986&amp;PID_0266&amp;REV_1412&amp;MI_00</HARDWAREID>
    <SERVICE>SPUVCbv</SERVICE>
    <DRIVER>SPUVCbv_x64.sys</DRIVER>
</DEVICE>
```

Comment: IC stands for Integrated Camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the dumps shows that the SPUVCbv_x64.sys causes the crash:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: fffff8800da0937d, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: fffff8800d343be0, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------


SYSTEM_SKU:  LENOVO_MT_3444

SYSTEM_VERSION:  ThinkPad X1 Carbon

BIOS_DATE:  04/29/2013

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  3444F9U

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  0B98401 Pro

BUGCHECK_P1: c0000005

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff8800da0937d

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff8800d343be0

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

FAULTING_IP: 
SPUVCbv_x64+937d
fffff880`0da0937d 89a900010000    mov     dword ptr [rcx+100h],ebp

CONTEXT:  fffff8800d343be0 -- (.cxr 0xfffff8800d343be0)
rax=0000000000000002 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=0000000000000004 rsi=fffffa800e94c160 rdi=fffffa800e849bc0
rip=fffff8800da0937d rsp=fffff8800d3445c0 rbp=0000000000000001
 r8=fffffa80109f4540  r9=fffffa800f114470 r10=0000000000000001
r11=000000000000000b r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000002
r14=fffff8a020fe9030 r15=0000000000000028
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010202
SPUVCbv_x64+0x937d:
fffff880`0da0937d 89a900010000    mov     dword ptr [rcx+100h],ebp ds:002b:00000000`00000100=????????
Resetting default scope

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: 9be

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3a

CPU_STEPPING: 9

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x3B

PROCESS_NAME:  chrome.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10240.9 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 0000000000000000 to fffff8800da0937d

STACK_TEXT:
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
nt!KiSystemServiceHandler
nt!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
nt!RtlDispatchException
nt!KiDispatchException
nt!KiExceptionDispatch
SPUVCbv_x64+0x937d 

    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\SPUVCbv_x64.sys
    Image name: SPUVCbv_x64.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Jul 21 04:54:29 2012
```

I see that the driver is over 3 years old.

[Download an install the latest driver](http://support.lenovo.com/vn/vi/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-carbon-type-34xx/3444/f9u/downloads/DS032187) that Lenovo offers for your ThinkPad X1 Carbon.

Comment: Funny thing is that I downloaded the Lenovo assistant exactly because I felt an update was necessary, it downloaded almost 1GB of files and still it solved nothing. Thanks for the direct link of the correct driver